# Простейшая нейронная сеть

Tags: javascript, html, нейронные-сети

нужен пример простейшей нейронной сети на JavaScript  способной обучаться,
или на любом другом языке но тогда без использования фреймворков(чтоб я сам смог переписать ее на  JavaScript).
2 входа, скрытый слой из 5 нейронов, выход. (обучение функциям XOR OR NAND AND)

нашел много проектов

- http://caza.la/synaptic/#/
- https://github.com/karpathy/convnetjs
- http://blog.webkid.io/neural-networks-in-javascript/
- http://cs.stanford.edu/people/karpathy/convnetjs/started.html
- https://medium.com/javascript-scene/how-to-build-a-neuron-exploring-ai-in-javascript-pt-1-c2726f1f02b2#.mi67zuk5q
- http://harthur.github.io/brain/

с теорией разобрался до метода обратного распространения ошибки, а вот с практикой пока напряженка. Прошу помощи.